# R: how to find where apply produces an error

Tags: r, error-handling, apply

The simple question is: how to find where in my data.frame is apply producing an error?

The details are:

I have a data.frame with geographic data (lat/long) of animals collected in the wild and stored in museums. This data comes from different sources (different museus and sites with listings from other museus). The animals may be listed in one or more sources, and sometimes we have different coordinates for the same animal - due to roundings or typos. What I want is to get all the coordinates - not NA - from each row, and calculate the maximum value minus the minimum, thus having the magnitude of the errors. Small errors may be ignored, otherwise I'll have to check them.

I'm using the following code:

```
#ALL is my data.frame with thousands of lines and about 100 columns
#ALL$LatDif will receive the differences in the coordinates for each row
#cLat <- c(18,21,46,54,63,77,85) # the columns with Latitudes from each museum
ALL$LatDif <- apply(ALL,1,function(x) if (any(!is.na(x[cLat]))) {max(x[cLat],na.rm=T)-min(x[cLat],na.rm=T)} else {NA})
```

It should work fine. But in some point it says:

```
Error in max(x[cLat], na.rm = T) - min(x[cLat], na.rm = T) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

traceback() gives me:

```
2: FUN(newX[, i], ...) at #1
1: apply(TUDO, 1, function(x) if (any(!is.na(x[cLat]))) {
       max(x[cLat], na.rm = T) - min(x[cLat], na.rm = T)
   } else {
       NA
   })
```

It seems there are characters somewhere in the middle of it, but I can't find where. is.character() didn't help me. Use a for takes a looong time. Any help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `options(error=recover)`. This will launch a browser session when the error is encountered, and in that session you can see what variable it's choking on. When `recover` asks you to choose a frame, select the deepest one. Then enter `x` to see which function is having a problem with.

For example:

```
R> df <-data.frame(a=c('1', '2', '3', "stop('STOP')", '4'))
R> options(error=recover)
R> apply(df, 1, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : STOP
# 
# Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   
# 
# 1: apply(df, 1, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
# 2: #1: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
# 3: #1: eval(parse(text = x))
# 4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
# 
Selection: 4
# Called from: stop("STOP")
Browse[1]> x
#              a 
# "stop('STOP')"
```

Comment: Thank you, Matthew! So one of the coordinates was " 3.433746e+00". Why didn't R treat this as a number? I thought it was THAT smart! :) Thanks again!

Comment: Should have: e.g, `str(read.table(text="a\n4.4e+00", header=TRUE))`. How'd you read it in?

Comment: The strange thing, Matthew and @Justin, is that outside recover, the value is shown as a normal number. ALL[which(ALL[,2] == "M-237927"),cLat] shows it as 3.433746, not " 3.433746e+00". What may be going on?

Comment: If I run this expression you passed me, it returns
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ a: num 4.4
Is this what you're asking? Or do you want to know how do I read my data file?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `str(ALL)` or just `class(ALL[cLat])`. I assume the column referenced by `cLat` will be `character`. But I cannot know for sure since you didn't supply any sample data that reproduces your problem.

However, assuming I'm right, you can sort out the offending values by doing this:

```
ALL[is.na(as.numeric(ALL[cLat])),]
```

Comment: Thanks, Justin! str(ALL[cLat]) returned: 'data.frame':   42876 obs. of  7 variables: all of them "num" beginning with lots of NA (that's all right). Your trial to sort out returned: Error in `[.data.frame`(ALL, is.na(as.numeric(ALL[cLat])), ) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' - I guess that's because they're already numbers?

Comment: `ALL[clat]` is a data.frame?  That would explain a lot...  Please either use `dput` on a portion of your data that replicates the problem or create a sample data set that we can use.

Comment: Yes, it is a data.frame. dput(ALL[which(ALL[,2] == "M-237927"),cLat],"test.txt") - that's the faulty line shown in recover - is giving a file that contains: structure(list(BR5LatD = NA_real_, CRIAlatitude = NA_real_, EDITlatitude = NA_real_, 
    GBIFLatitude = NA_real_, ARCTOSDEC_LAT = NA_real_, OUTLat = 3.433746, AMNHLATD = 3.433746), .Names = c("BR5LatD", "CRIAlatitude", 
"EDITlatitude", "GBIFLatitude", "ARCTOSDEC_LAT", "OUTLat", "AMNHLATD"
), row.names = 1940L, class = "data.frame")

Comment: Well, the solution was to include an as.numeric() inside the min and max functions. It seems that to display the values already converts them to numbers, but not to pass them to these functions. Thank you both, guys!